# Java, EoT symbol gets saved in txt file when copying (Java, TCP, socket)

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, eot

Hello I wrote a programm that sends a TCP protocol to a server or can be used as a server to receive protocols.

This is the transmitter method:

```
public void tell(String msg, Actor sender) {
    InetAddress addr;
    ServerSocket svSocket;
    try {
        addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Socket sock = new Socket(addr, port);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        ps.println(msg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the receiver method:

```
public void run() {
    Printer printer = new Printer();
    ServerSocket svSocket;
    try {
        svSocket = new ServerSocket(this.port);
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        String message = "";
        while(!message.equals("\u0004")){
            sock = svSocket.accept();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            message = br.readLine();
            printer.tell(message, null);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It works to send simple messages and have them print out but as soon as I want to send files via. command line:

Start jar, create server with port 5555, localhost as address, copy.txt the file to create.

```
java -jar foo.jar -l 5555 > copy.txt
```

Start jar, create client with target port 5555, localhost as address, myFile.txt the file to send.

```
 java -jar foo.jar localhost 5555 < myFile.txt
```

Everything works, but it saves an EoT symbol at the very end of the file. It doesn't bother too much in txts but it corrupts images.

How can I solve this issue ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is fundamentally broken. You're sending text, meaning you can't send binary files like images at all. You're using a special character to indicate end-of-transmission, unnecessarily. You're not closing connections. Your "transmissions" seem to consist of single lines (of text, which doesn't work like I said)... I'd recommend you put all this into garbage, go find an example on how to transfer files over socket (there are thousands of them that actually work) and start over. Are you perhaps trying to "translate" C++ code to Java? If so, that won't work.

Comment: No I didn't try to translate my code. I already have a code which allows me to transfer files but none of them uses the case of mine where I use those "> copy.txt" commands to actually work with the Path of files. I can't really access the filepath inside my code which is really annoying. already tried other ways but none seem to work properly. I can't work with them because the main(args[]) doesn't include them and just simply ignores them ( '>', '<', and path after that).

Comment: If you're redirecting, then there are no paths involved. Only streams (`System.in` and `System.out`). But your data transfer code is still bonkers.

Comment: The `<` and `>` aren't going to be included in `args`. They're not parameters, they're redirection arguments for the **shell**, not your program.